# How to publish a web site using Visual Studio Express Web 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, publishing, visual-studio-express

I need to publish a web site (DLLs built in release mode) using Visual Studio 2010 Express (Web Developer).

Any idea like using batch, or whatever, since I don't have the professional version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are doing.  If it's an internal IT arrangement where you have servers that already are configured with your base environment, dependencies and what not  you can just use technologies like msbuild or MS Deploy / [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) to syncronize your changes into dev, test and production ( or whatever you call it ).  Check out Scott Gu's blog article:

[VS2010 Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

But if you are creating a product that will ship to customers ( like Sharepoint or Team Foundation Server )  then I would look at Windows Installer / WiX / InstallShield to create a complete system for shrinkwrapping and deploying your application and all of it's nderlying dependencies and configuration details.

Comment: @Sir I got the idea, and did it. Okay it is a ready zip file to transfer my project to the production server, on the other hand, I want to get the dll files which may be created from the App Folder.. I need this since dlls are faster than .cs files. Isn't it sir?